# JSONata : walk tree and return all object names

Tags: jsonata

JSONata has the [$keys()](http://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions.html#keysobject) function which returns all the names associated with an object. I am trying to recursively apply this in order to return all of the object names that exist in a JSON tree.

[This example](http://try.jsonata.org/By9SUfOjM) returns the object names in nested arrays.

In an attempt to eliminate the array nesting I came up with [this query](http://try.jsonata.org/B1BRIMOoz) ... which seems to work fine.

However, when I apply the exact same query to different JSON data [as shown here](http://try.jsonata.org/SJrheXdsz) the results are not fully flattened.

Q: What is the proper way to construct this query so that the results are fully flattened?

and/or

Q: What characteristic distinguishes these two datasets to account for the difference in the structure of the results?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I figured this out.

[This query](http://try.jsonata.org/rk7rV4OsM) uses explicit calls to $map() and $reduce()+$append() to flatten it.

[This query](http://try.jsonata.org/ryamHNdif) accomplishes the same thing using more a standard JSONata dot (.) query notation.